# How can we say that the universe is expanding

Tags: universe, fate-of-universe

How can we say that universe is expanding as we r sure about that

> energy is neither created nor destroyed
>   then from where does this more energy come from

Comment: Your question is unclear. You where does "this extra energy" come from. There is no extra energy. It's not clear why you think there would be.

Comment: Means there's no extra energy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is counterfactual.

Comment: @NeilPatel Why do you think there would need to be extra energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theory of the expanding universe comes from Hubble.

Hubble studied galaxies and plotted their red shift vs. their estimated distance. From that he found that there seems to be a correlation between distance and redshift.

And since redshift is caused by something flying away from us, stronger redshift means its flying away faster. So since the further away a galaxy is, the stronger its redshift, implies that the further away something is from earth, the faster it flies away from us (thats where the Hubble constant comes from, it basically says how much the redshift increases if an object is a certain distance from earth).

From this the model formed, that the reason for them to be flying faster away from us, the further away they are, is because the universe is expanding. This model fits all of our current evidence and checks out with other implications as far as I know.

There are however other explentations on why stuff that is further away is more redshifted. At the moment the "Expanding Universe" model is the most accepted one in the community of scientists.